# Sacrificing expression of intent for memory management

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm pretty new at C programming, and this type of thing keeps popping up. As a simple example, suppose I have a `struct http_header` with some `char` pointers:

```
struct http_header {
    char* name;
    char* value;
};
```

I want to fill an `http_header` where `value` is the string representation of an int. I "feel" like, semantically, I should be able to write a function that takes in an empty header pointer, a name string, and an `int` and fills out the header appropriately.

```
void fill_header(struct http_header *h, char* name, int value)
{
    h->name = name;
    char *value_str = malloc(100);
    sprintf(value_str, "%d", value);
    h->value = value_str;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    struct http_header h;
    char *name = "Header Name";
    int val = 42;
    fill_header(&h, name, val);
    ...
    free(h.value);
}
```

Here, the calling code reads exactly as my intent, but in this case I'm creating the `value` string dynamically, which means I'd have to free it later. That doesn't smell right to me; it seems like the caller then knows too much about the implementation of `fill_header`. And in actual implementations it may not be so easy to know what to free: consider filling an array of `http_header`s where only one of them needed to have its value `malloc`ed.

To get around this, I'd have to create the string beforehand:

```
void fill_header2(struct http_header *h, char* name, char *value_str)
{
    h->name = name;
    h->value = value_str;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    struct http_header h;
    char *name = "Header Name";
    int value = 42;

    char value_str[100];
    sprintf(value_str, "%d", value);
    fill_header2(&h, name, value_str);
}
```

As this pattern continues down the chain of structures with pointers to other structures, I end up doing so much work in top level functions the lower level ones seem hardly worth it. Furthermore, I've essentially sacrificed the "fill a header with an `int`" idea which I set out to write in the first place. I'm I missing something here? Is there some pattern or design choice that will make my life easier *and* keep my function calls expressing my intent?

P.S. Thanks to all at Stackoverfow for being the best professor I've ever had.

Comment: This problem is called "object ownership", and it's a synonym for "pain". There are several solutions (from auto pointers to garbage collection), but I vote on the most efficient way: *design* the ownership strategy of a program/class/method (function). Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would go with the first approach (with a twist), and also provide a `destroy` function:

```
struct http_header *make_header(char *name, int value)
{
    struct http_header *h = malloc(sizeof *h);
    /* ... */
    return h;
}

void destroy_header(struct http_header *h)
{
    free(h->name);
    free(h);
}
```

This way the caller doesn't have to know anything about `http_header`.

You might also get away with a version that leaves the main allocation (the struct itself) to the caller and does it's own internal allocation. Then you would have to provide a `clear_header` which only frees that `fill` allocated. But this `clear_header` leaves you with a partially-valid object.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. See also: factory pattern ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern ). It is used when the object creation is more complex than just create it with *new* or *malloc()*. Also, welcome to the world of real programming.

Comment: Thanks, all. I suppose encapsulation in constructor/destructor type calls is what I need. I've always heard warnings that "malloc is slow"---and of course it is, compared to allocating on the stack---but how concerned do I *really* need to be? Using it repeatedly for little structures like this seems inefficient if I'll be doing it often. But in production code would that make a significant difference? I guess, if it is properly encapsulated, I could change it later to dole out pre-allocated headers instead of using malloc/free.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is simply that you are programming asymmetrically. You should once and for all decide who is responsible for the string inside your structure. Then you should have *two* functions, not only one, that should be called something like `header_init` and `header_destroy`.

For the init function I'd be a bit more careful. Check for a `0` argument of your pointer, and initialize your DS completely, something like `*h = (http_header){ .name = name }`. You never know if you or somebody will end up in adding another field to your structure. So by that at least all other fields are initialized with `0`.

Comment: I like that idea, "programming asymmetrically." You're right, I should be thinking more in those terms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new at C programming, you might perhaps want to use the [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/). Boehm's GC works very well in practice, and by using it systematically in your own code you could use `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` and never bother about calling `free` or `GC_free`.

Hunting memory leaks in C (or even C++) code is often a headache. There are tools (like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)) which can help you, but you could decide to not bother by using Boehm's GC.

Garbage collection (and memory management) is a **global property** of a program, so if you use Boehm's GC you should decide that early.

Comment: Thanks, but my question wasn't really about memory leaks. More about design decisions.

Comment: But memory leaks are often the consequence of design decisions. And design decisions should also be dictated by the global properties of your program -those properties which are not modular!

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to your problem is that of object ownership, as others have suggested.  The *simplest* solution to your particular problem is, however, to use a `char` array for `value`, i.e., `char value[12]`. 2^32 has 10 decimal digits, +1 for the sign, +1 for the null-terminator.

You should ensure that 1) int is not larger than 32-bits at compile-time, 2) ensure that the value is within some acceptable range (HTTP codes have only 3 digits) before calling sprintf, 3) use `snprintf`.

So by using a static array you get rid of the ownership problem, AND you use less memory.

Comment: Do you mean a char array in the definition of `struct http_header`? I was hoping to have that be a bit more generic, and not be limited to purely `int`s  for `value`s.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. In general, avoid dynamic memory allocation if doing so is feasible (e.g., won't waste memory), so you will avoid any issues of object ownership.